# BASIC JOIN test in Hackerrank

Tags: sql, mysql

Given the `CITY` and `COUNTRY` tables, query the names of all the continents `COUNTRY.Continent` and their respective average city populations `CITY.Population` rounded down to the nearest integer.

Note: `CITY.CountryCode` and `COUNTRY.Code` are matching key columns.

Here's my input:

```
SELECT country.continent, ROUND(AVG(city.population), 0) 
FROM city
JOIN country ON city.countrycode = country.code
GROUP BY country.continent;
```

OUTPUT

| continent | avg_population |
| --- | --- |
| Asia | 693038 |
| Europe | 175138 |
| Oceania | 109190 |
| South America | 147435 |
| Africa | 274439 |

It says that it's a wrong answer.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect it's the `ROUND()` function that's the issue. It'll only round down for values below `0.5`. Otherwise it'll round up. The question states to round down to the nearest integer. I'd therefore suggest you try the `FLOOR()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `ROUND`, it will will round down values below `0.5` only(as mentioned in the comment by @fuber).

There are two ways to solve it:

1. Use `ROUND` but subtract `0.5` to round down all values even if its greater than 0.5:

```
SELECT CO.CONTINENT, ROUND(AVG(C.POPULATION)-0.5)
FROM CITY AS C
INNER JOIN COUNTRY AS CO
ON C.COUNTRYCODE = CO.CODE
GROUP BY CO.CONTINENT;
```

2. Use `FLOOR`:

```
SELECT CO.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(C.POPULATION))
FROM CITY AS C
INNER JOIN COUNTRY AS CO
ON C.COUNTRYCODE = CO.CODE
GROUP BY CO.CONTINENT;
```